# Where should I set up click listeners when working with listview/gridview?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview, adapter

When I work with list of views such as listview, recyclerview, gridview, etc., where should I declare item click listeners?

For instance, I have a GridView and a custom adapter class extending ArrayAdapter. Can someone please tell me which one of the following two cases is a better way to use a click listener in general?

1. Inside the activity/fragment in which the GridView is set up like:

   `GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(parameters) { }
   });
   gridView.setAdapter(adapter);`
2. Inside the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method in CustomAdapter like:

   `convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() ... );`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did I get a negative vote.. I couldn't find any duplicate question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on you how you want, Like if you want to access some activity variable with your item click listener then its better write first one and also if you want to single row click event then definitely first one is better but if you need more click event of subview which is list item then you need to define inside of adapter,

Like I have list item with one plus and minus button and also I want to redirect to detail screen on full item click then it will be better I will define click event inside of adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one additional question though. If I want a single row click event, why is the first one 'definitely' better? Is it always recommended to implement a onItemClickListener from activity like the first approach if I want a click event from the entire row without subview-click-events? If better, why is that better? (in terms of performance?)

Comment: Better Because sometimes we need to use some activity variable which has not all will be available in the adapter so it's better and one more thing its predefine architecture of Android which provides us list view click event so it reduces code complexity.

Comment: I see. Now I have a better vision regarding this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your need, if you want to consider single for entire `grid item` then go with first approach of setting `onItemClickListener` to `grid` but if your `grid` has to respond to individual view clicks inside it then go for second approach of responding to click in adapter

Comment: Aren't those two approaches essentially end up with the same behavior? I have a GridView and when I click on each item, it takes the screen to a new activity with the clicked grid item. However, I think I can achieve this by both GridView.setOnItemClickListener or view.setOnClickListener in getView in the CustomAdapter class. I can respond to individual view clicks by using onItemClickListener as well. I was wondering if there are any performance differences between the two approaches.

Comment: I understood your answer after reading @Dhaval Solanki's answer. But If I want a click event for the entire grid item, why is it a better practice to go with the first approach? Does the performance get worse or if I go with the second approach for the entire-row-click-event?